# Rails 4 - after clicking an HTML anchor or "link_to" the page doesn't move on a given URL

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I am facing the problem that (sometimes) when I click on a link in a view

```
= link_to 'Page name', abcde_path
```

I am not redirected on the URL in `abcde_path`. Even if I do:

```
<a href="/abcde">Page name</a>
```

the result is the same - I am not redirected on the `website.com/abcde` URL.

If I open the page in a new tab, the page is loaded though.

I have no idea how to debug it - what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

disable your turbolinks and see if it helps.

this is just a guess, as the question is a bit vague and i am having trouble understanding the exact problem

in views/layouts/application.html.erb

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>`